# Custom validate and submit don't works

Tags: users, forms

I made my custom module, and wanted to do some staff in the validation and submission handlers. My Fields are in two field sets:

- Member profile, with username and password
- Company profile, with company name, URL, location, and logo

I am also using the #states attribute on some fields, but everything works except the validation and submission handlers.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_profile_form':
      // Only pre-render works.  
      $form['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_pre_render';
      // I try to empty fields with states attribute, but without success. Disabled work OK.
      $form['field_company_url']['und']['0']['value']['#states'] = array(
       'empty' => array(':input[name="field_company_confidential[und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
       'disabled' => array(':input[name="field_company_confidential[und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),);


      // These don't work as expected.
      $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_validate';
      $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_submit';

      // I also tried this one.
      // $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_submit'; 
  }
}

function mymodule_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  // I want to download the image from another website and set as logo.
}

function mymodule_user_profile_form_validate($form, &$form_state) { 
  //I need to check if checkbox is checked to empty all other fields.
  if ($form_state['values']['field_company_confidential'] == TRUE) {
    $form_state['values']['field_company_url']['und']['0'] = '';
  }

  return $form;
}
```

When I try to access `$form_state['values']`, I don't get any value.

[image: screenshot]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you do a dpm($form['#submit']) after you have added yours? What happens if you add at the beginning of the array, with array_unshift()? For submit, it's possible that someone's (another submit, or a hook) is doing a drupal_goto() or something like that. Try using the form_id specific form_alter and dpm() #submit in form.inc, right before they are called.

Comment: I want in validate function to empty all company fields if chekbox is checked.

In submit function i need to download logo from other website and use that picture as logo.

Comment: As side note, form validation, and submission handlers don't return any value; the `return $form;` line needs to be removed.

Comment: Yes I removed line {return $form;}.

I always try to var_dump('some text'); In all function, and when I put that in validate or submit or just try dpm($form); notheng happens.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was with devel module. 
When I disable it and try again all job everything works perfect.
So maybe was some bugs with devel module, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think that has to be related to hooks registry. Everytime you add or remove a hook implementation in your custom module, you have to visit the module list page (no need to deactivate or activate modules) to let Drupal refresh its hooks registry.