# How do I retrieve values using $form_state?

Tags: forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom validate and submit don't works](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34307/custom-validate-and-submit-dont-works)

I am using Drupal 7 `$form_state['values']` to get values from all fields, but the array is empty, and when I use `dsm()` there is no value.

[image: screenshot]

Hi, please this is maybe complex question but I really need help, I can't finish my task almost 3 days. If I need to write somewhere else you just say.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_profile_form':

    //only pre-render works  
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_pre_render';
//I try to empty fields with states attribute, but without success. Disabled work OK.
$form['field_company_url']['und']['0']['value']['#states'] = array(
     'empty' => array(':input[name="field_company_confidential[und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
     'disabled' => array(':input[name="field_company_confidential[und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),);


         //these two don't work as expected
         $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_validate';
         $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_submit';

        //also try this one but nothing
        //$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_profile_form_submit'; 
    }
}

function mymodule_user_profile_form_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
//here I want to download image from other website and set as logo
}

function mymodule_user_profile_form_validate($form, &$form_state) { 
//here I need to check if checkbox is checked emty all other fields
    if ($form_state['values']['field_company_confidential'] == TRUE){
     //THEN set all other fields empty
        $form_state['values']['field_company_url']['und']['0'] = '';
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: You should show the code you are using. There are many Drupal 7 modules that use `$form_state['values']`; `$form_state['values']` is also used from modules included with Drupal. All those modules work as expected.

Comment: I want to make validation and to empty fields in validate function if one checkbox is checked. I am using form alter. 

I have another question on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34307/custom-validate-and-submit-dont-works

I want to made some validation in want to get all values, and if checkbox is checked i want to empty all fields.
Where do you want to put my code, because that is similiar question I wrote, but still no answer?

Comment: Just edit your question, and show the code you are using.

Comment: In other words, this is a follow-up to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34307/custom-validate-and-submit-dont-works.

Comment: Yes It is. But as I said my validate and submit function don't work.
At first time they have worked without problems, but later I added two fieldsets using Group field module. Next I added some code using #states and now I can't call these functions.

Comment: Still, both the questions are about the same topic: The validation handler doesn't work. If you have updates for a question that has not been answered, you can edit the question, instead of asking another question.